# displaying labels in marathi language

Tags: extjs, label, non-english

i am tring to display lable of form in marathi language for that
am creating  marathi.js 
this my mararhi.js

```
if(Ext.app.formPanel) 
{
     Ext.apply(Ext.app.formPanel.prototype, 
                      {
                       selectUser:'नाव'
                      }
     );
}
```

and my other js file contain this

```
var Ext.app.formPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel,{
     selectUser:'Select User',
     initComponent : function(config) {
                 Ext.apply(this, {
                           title      : 'User Rights',
                           bodyStyle  : 'padding: 10px; background-color: #DFE8F6',
                           labelWidth : 100,
                           width      : 755,
                           id         : 'formUserRights',
                           renderTo:'adminpanel',
                           items      : [   id: 'User',
                                        fieldLabel:this.selectUser,
                                        width:200
                            ] //items
                 });//Ext.apply
                 Ext.app.formPanel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
         }//init component
}); //yuyu
......
....
```

but it can not work 
it gives error `; missing before 
var Ext.app.formPanel = Ext.extend.....`
but when i checked all carefully every thing is correctly nested.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related but you are using wrong syntax for `items: []`, `[]` means array and what's inside those parenthesis looks more like an object. You probably meant `items: [{ id: 'User'}]`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the syntax error that *vava* noted in his comment above.

Second, you should not *var* the 'Ext.app.formPanel' *namespace*.

Third, *initComponent* does not pass any arguments.

Fourth, you need to *call* the superclass, not *apply* it - also no need to pass arguments, as there are none.

```
Ext.ns('Ext.app');
Ext.app.formPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
selectUser : 'Select User',
initComponent : function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        title : 'User Rights',
        bodyStyle : 'padding: 10px; background-color: #DFE8F6',
        labelWidth : 100,
        width : 755,
        id : 'formUserRights',
        renderTo : 'adminpanel',
        items : [ {
            id : 'User',
            fieldLabel : this.selectUser,
            width : 200
        } ]
    });
    Ext.app.formPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
});
```

On a side note, I prefer not to use the Ext namespace for my app code, there is a chance for collision that way. I would suggest creating your own namespace.

Enjoy this one on the house, with the hope that someday you will actually award answers.